# Translate this SQL to jOOQ

Tags: sql, translate, jooq

I'm failing to translate this SQL into working jOOQ:

```
SELECT * FROM product p JOIN
  ( SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT max(product_rev_id) as maxi
      FROM product_rev
      GROUP BY product_id) as a
    JOIN product_rev as t ON t.product_rev_id = maxi
   WHERE valid_to IS NOT NULL 
) as z ON z.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE p.product_id in(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Here's the SQL-Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7816/1

I tried several hours, but it's getting a mess with all that aliases and jOOQ.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to translate such nested queries to jOOQ is by looking at jOOQ sub queries as composable, reusable elements. I.e.

```java
// Assuming this
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Then write the inner-most derived table
Table<?> a = table(
    select(max(PRODUCT_REV.PRODUCT_REV_ID).as("maxi"))
   .from(PRODUCT_REV)
   .groupBy(PRODUCT_REV.PRODUCT_ID)
).as("a");

// Then use a in the middle derived table
ProductRev t = PRODUCT_REV.as("t");
Table<?> z = table(
    select()
   .from(a)
   .join(t).on(t.PRODUCT_REV_ID.eq(a.field("maxi", PRODUCT_REV.PRODUCT_REV_ID.getType())))
   .where(t.VALID_TO.isNotNull())
).as("z");

// Finally, the outer-most query
Product p = PRODUCT.as("p");
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(p)
   .join(z).on(z.field(PRODUCT_REV.PRODUCT_ID).eq(p.PRODUCT_ID))
   .where(p.PRODUCT_ID.in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
   .fetch();
```

#### Alternative, using views

From your query, I suspect that the only really dynamic part is

```sql
WHERE p.product_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This means that you might as well create a view in your database for the rest of the query, and query that view from your client.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. When I enter the code as you have it above for one of my own tables I get an error for the section `eq(a.field("maxi"))` that says "Cannot resolve method 'eq(org.jooq.Field<capture<?>>)'" Do you know what I might be missing?

Comment: @ArnoldSpence: Thanks for the hint. My answer wasn't entirely correct. In this case, the data type needs to be supplied (or rawtype casting would work, too)